Sawtooth Signal Delivery to a Capacitive Load
I am trying to drive a capacitive load with a sawtooth of around 20 MHz, and wish for minimal back-reflection of the waveform, since the load needs to experience as much of the original RMS voltage as technically possible.
I understand, traditionally, that to efficiently drive a reactive load with a sinusoidal signal, a matching network is required.
However, in this case, a sawtooth can be understood as a Fourier Series of all harmonics of the fundamental, which, to my knowledge, is highly non-trivial (and perhaps impossible) to match, as it would require a flat frequency response of the load + matching network.
Does anyone have any insight or references into this challenge?

Driving a capacitive load with a signal which has steep dvdt (the falling edge of your sawtooth) requires a lot of current from your driver. How close to an ideal sawtooth are you aiming for?

Just to clarify - are you sure you mean a sawtooth waveform, as opposed to a triangle waveform?  Very different harmonic signatures, bandwidth requirements, etc.

What is the load, and where is it located? -- can the amplifier be directly adjacent, or must there be a transmission line in the way? Is the load purely capacitive, mixed (R+C?), or complex (e.g. piezo actuator)?

Driving a capacitive load with a sawtooth waveform, that is, both leading and trailing edges have finite slope, is straightforward from an adjacent amplifier. You simply arrange a current output of the right magnitude, and the capacitive load integrates that to a ramp.
'Wish for minimal back reflection' hints that you have a remote amplifier, connected by a transmission line.
To match a capacitive load into a transmission line, the standard approach is to design a singly-terminated lowpass filter, with the input matched to the line impedance, with an open circuit output. The load capacitance is then absorbed into the filter's output capacitor. For this arrangement, you would drive the transmission line with a standard 50 ohm output amplifier.
The line impedance and the load capacitance together define the maximum bandwidth of the lowpass filter, for any given order, through the filter design. You will only be able to match harmonics up to this frequency into the load. Higher frequencies than this will be reflected.
For instance, the following 3rd order Butterworth design will drive a load of 45 pF from a 50 ohm transmission line, with a corner frequency of 106 MHz. I used this online filter design tool.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
If you want to get a wider bandwidth into your load, you must reduce the impedance of your transmission line, or your load capacitance.

Could you explain (or show simulations) how the transmission line will be terminated in the case of a current source?

@TimWilliams it wouldn't be, if you mean a current source driving the transmission line. That is designed to be driven with a 50 ohm source.

Ok, so the first paragraph is separate from the rest, just wanted to clarify that.
